# Definition of "pick up"

Tags: meaning

How is "picked up" in this sentence defined?

> After seeing the support for the show, NBC **picked up** the series for thirteen episodes

I think it means "acquire and begin producing [some media franchise]" but I couldn't find a dictionary confirming that.

Comment: I don't know that they took over production, but they did "acquire" it to the extent of buying rights for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to **pick up**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pick+up) a phrasal verb

> - To come into possession of
> - acquire, procure, gain
> - to buy

In this case a network bought a TV production to add to and enhance its broadcast schedule.